# lighttpd + php-cgi: Memory increase crazily if there's syntax error in the php file

Tags: php, fastcgi, lighttpd

I use `lighttpd` as the webserver, and module `mod_fastcgi` is on. So I can fetch `php file` with `lighttpd`.

Here is a segment of my configure file.

```
fastcgi.server =(
  ".php"=>
  (
    (
       "bin-path" => "/usr/local/webserver/php/bin/php-cgi",
       "socket" => "/data/online/webim/socket/php-fcgi.socket",
       "min-procs" => 100,
       "max-procs" => 100,
       "check-local" => "disable",
       "bin-environment" => (
         "PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN" => "10",
         "PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS" => "1000"
       ),
       "bin-copy-environment" => (
         "PATH", "SHELL", "USER"
       ),
       "broken-scriptfilename" => "enable"
    )
  )
)
```

Once, I made a mistake. A **`syntax error`** is left in the php file.
Then I send many(10000) requests to the webserver.
Soon, the memory used by the php-cgi progresses start to `increase crazily`.

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
26829 www       16   0  290m 114m 105m S    0  1.9   0:16.82 php-cgi
25410 www       15   0  287m 112m 105m S    0  1.9   0:17.71 php-cgi
30137 www       16   0  290m 112m 102m S    0  1.8   0:15.38 php-cgi
31099 www       21   0  288m 111m 103m S    0  1.8   0:16.77 php-cgi
30327 www       20   0  287m 110m 103m S    0  1.8   0:22.50 php-cgi
25291 www       16   0  288m 109m 101m S    0  1.8   0:18.26 php-cgi
25413 www       15   0  286m 108m 102m S    0  1.8   0:16.34 php-cgi
30136 www       16   0  288m 108m 101m S    0  1.8   0:15.75 php-cgi
25283 www       18   0  288m 108m 101m S    0  1.8   0:16.29 php-cgi
```

a single process has 100MB+ memory..
And memory keeps on increasing, the machine becomes slower and slower...

So why this happens? why the memory increase? Any answer, advice or link is welcome. Thanks~